# streaming radio station audio in flex/flash builder 4.6 multi-platform mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, flash, apache-flex, builder

I have been unsuccessful in getting this piece of code to work, and it's been driving me crazy.  I know I am really close, but the solution is eluding me.  I was hoping someone could help me!  Here's what my activity code looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
        import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
        import flash.media.Video;
        import flash.net.NetConnection;
        import flash.net.NetStream;


        private var streamURL:String = "http://twit.am/listen";
        private var connection:NetConnection;
        private var stream:NetStream;

        public function NetConnectionExample():void {
            connection = new NetConnection();
            connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
            connection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
            connection.connect(null);

        }

        private function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
            switch (event.info.code) {
                case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                    connectStream();
                    break;
                case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
                        trace("Stream not found: " + streamURL);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
            trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function connectStream():void {

            stream = new NetStream(connection);
            stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);

            stream.play(streamURL);
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a "client" variable to the stream and adding an "onMetaData" method to the class:

```
private function connectStream():void {

    stream = new NetStream(connection);

    stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
    stream.client = { onMetaData : onMetaData };

    stream.play(streamURL);
}

protected function onMetaData(data : Object) : void
{
    // This can be empty
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.  unfortunately it still doesn't work.  I'd be willing to PayPal you some cash if you could help me figure out this problem once and for all.  Any takers?